# inequality in normed spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

If we have
$$\|u\left(t\right)\|_X \leq \|v\left(t\right)\|_Y+\|w\left(t\right)\|_Z,$$

can we conclude that $$\operatorname{ess sup}\|u\left(t\right)\|_X \leq \operatorname{ess sup} \|v\left(t\right)\|_Y+\operatorname{ess sup}\|w\left(t\right)\|_Z,$$ where $X,Y,Z$ are Banach spaces?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  I made a few minor TeX edits to your post, in particular I replaced `esssup` with `\operatorname{ess sup}` and replaced `||u||` with `\|u\|`.

Comment: I assume, we are given sets $U\subseteq X,\ V\subseteq Y,\ W\subseteq Z$ from where $u,v,w$ take their value. Do we also have some measures on these spaces, or how do you mean '*essential supremum*'?

Comment: $ ess\ sup \|u\left(t\right)\|_X=inf\left\{c>0;\|u \left(t\right)\|\leq c\ p.p  \ t\in \left(0,T\right)\right\}$

Comment: Your essential supremum definition seems strange. Does $u(t)$ belong to some function space or what is u(t)?

Comment: $ u \in L^{\infty}\left(0,T;X\right)$